# Adding text to input, only adds second part to last line

Tags: powershell, foreach

I've written a small script helping me to more efficiently move folders from one place to another by generating complete commands based on an input file.

Code:

```cs
Get-Content inputfile.txt |
    ForEach-Object {
        "robocopy D:\Home\" + $_ + " H:\Home-E\" + $_
    } | Set-Content outputfile.txt
```

Now this works fine, except the last part only gets added to the last line.

The output file looks like this:

```
robocopy D:\Home\ewja 
robocopy D:\Home\ewst
robocopy D:\Home\ewwi
robocopy D:\Home\ezga H:\Home-E\ezga
```

Does anybody know why the second part gets cut off from the first lines?

Comment: maybe this works: `cat inputfile.txt | % { "robocopy D:\Home\$_ H:\Home-E\$_" } > outfile.txt`

Comment: I got the same result, but it made me realize spaces in the input-file may be the problem. I'll check that out and get back to this thread.

Comment: Yeah, spaces after each line in my input-file messed everything up.Thanks for making me realize! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **problem was a purely *visual* one:**

The trailing space after each line of your input file was simply so long - each line but the last was right-space-padded to 119 characters - **what the 2nd reference to `$_` expanded to** (the part starting with `H:\Home-E\...`) **was merely *scrolled out of view*.**
Only the *last* line was *not* space-padded, so for the last command the *entire* output line was visible in the console.

Note that the **resulting commands would still have *worked***, however, because the amount of whitespace between the arguments passed to a command doesn't mater.

To fix the problem at the source:

```
Get-Content inputfile.txt |
    ForEach-Object {
        $_ = $_ -replace '\s+$' # trim trailing whitespace from input line
        "robocopy D:\Home\" + $_ + " H:\Home-E\" + $_
    } | Set-Content outputfile.txt
```

Note that string interpolation in double-quoted strings can make construction of the command string somewhat simpler `"robocopy D:\Home\$_ H:\Home-E\$_"`

However, neither approach is generally robust, in that it can **break the constructed `robocopy` command with filenames that have embedded spaces**, for instance, so you'd have to perform quoting / escaping of the input filenames.
The specific approach to that depends on what shell will end up executing the file containing the constructed commands.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out spaces after each line in my input-file messed everything up. Removed the spaces and everything worked as expected.

Comment: Spaces at the end of input lines do not explain the behavior described in your question. Try `'abc ', 'def ' | % { "robocopy D:\Home\" + $_ + " H:\Home-E\" + $_ }`. It would be interesting to know the true cause.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it tomorrow when I get access to the input file again and let you know, but it's weird that I got the same result with metix' suggestion which is quite different if that isn't the case.
I could upload the input-file too if you want to take a look at it.

Comment: metix' command is _functionally equivalent_ to yours, so I'm not surprised it gave the same result. If you can give me a link to an uploaded input file, I'm happy to take a look at it. What PowerShell version, by the way?

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll get back to you tomorrow with all the information :)

Comment: Version: 4.0
Original input-file: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=06938731863205210673

Comment: Your example worked fine btw:
    PS D:\> 'abc ', 'def ' | % { "robocopy D:\Home\" + $_ + " H:\Home-E\" + $_ }

robocopy D:\Home\abc  H:\Home-E\abc
robocopy D:\Home\def  H:\Home-E\def

Comment: Thanks. I've solved the mystery - please see my answer.